# 24 hour/12 hour clock problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app it takes the time, but i've noticed that in settings on the device if the user has it set to 24 hour clock, it works as expected where HH from the current date returns, say 14. But if they have it set to 12 hour clock, it returns as 2. Is there a way of getting around this?

Comment: I didnt really understand the problem. 14 should come out as 2 in the 12hour clock

Comment: You may also want to see [Apple QA1480](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1480.html) which explains how to handle an issue with NSDateFormatter and the 24-hour time setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using this code, I always get the 24-hour clock value.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate* now = [NSDate date]; 
int hours = [[cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now] hour];
```